# How to display the captured image preview in Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I am developing ionic 3 application where i want to capture multiple(3) images with camera, display the preview of the images below camera icon and upload the images along with remaining information.

**I am not able to display the preview of captured images.**

```
let options: CaptureImageOptions = { limit: 3 };
this.mediaCapture.captureImage(options)
  .then(data: MediaFile[]) => {
      this.images = data;
    },
    (err: CaptureError) => console.error(err)
  );
```

HTML Code -

```
      <div *ngFor="let image of images">
        <img src="{{image.fullPath}}" />
      </div>
```

I am getting following image array in data: MediaFile[] variable
[image]

When i bind the full path of image to img src, it show nothing when i print the fullpath it gives following image path.

> file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1534070545509.jpg

Please get me out from this problem.

Comment: what happenes when you open the path in browser? do you see the image?

Comment: when i capture image it saved to my mobile storage at above mentioned path..Are you asking me to open that path in my mobile browser???

Answer (score 1):

Please try This :
1. st in TS file :

```
async captureImage(useAlbum: boolean) {

    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
      ...useAlbum ? {sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM} : {}
    }

    const imageData = await this.camera.getPicture(options);

    this.base64Image = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${imageData}`;


}
```

2. HTML file :

img src="{{base64Image}}" alt="" class="image_container

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<div *ngFor="let image of images">
        <img src="'data:image/jpeg;base64,' +{{image.fullPath}}" />
</div>
```